# Counter in ActionScript 3.0 with...PHP or?

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I am doing this flash banners for multiple clients and one major request is to have some sort of counter so they know how many times the banner has been clicked.

I know how to do it in ActionScript 3.0, I make a simple var:int and i increase it +1 when a click is made on the banner. What do I do with the value of this var(say its 121) where do I store it online so its safe and can be changed by multiple flash banners(as3).

But how do I save this information so next time when the banner is loaded(on diffrent webpages) the number of clicks is whatever it was last time it was loaded.

Should I look into PHP for that ? I have no clue how to do this... some examples, tutorials, whatever works... would be much appreciated.(I am a designer, not programmer...please dont speak php-ish, or you know... :D)

I've googled a bit, and found some help, but i am still confused, and much of it its not AS3, I'm thinking maybe stuff has evolved a bit since the stuff that I found(2008)...

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to store (and fetch) the value somewhere - either in the DB, in a text-file, ...

I'd go search for a tutorial on PHP+MySQL. If you don't like PHP-ish, you're probably better of finding another solution though :p

Example tutorial: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the data you want be retrievable/update-able from multiple clients, to be stored on a server.

You can use any server side language with a database.

*Server Languages* : PHP, ASP.net, JSP, ColdFusion
*Database* : MySQL, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2 etc..

Use whatever combination you are comfortable with.

In general:

1. You have a web app that increments the counter in the database
2. call the page using URLLoader from your AS3 banner.

**Database**

```
counter_table
-------------
counter     INT
```

**PHP File**

```
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
mysql_select_db('database_name');
mysql_query('UPDATE counter_table SET counter = counter + 1');
```

**AS3 Banner**

```
// url request with your php page address
var scriptRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.example.com/script.php");

// loader
var scriptLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

// load page to trigger database update
scriptLoader.load(scriptRequest);
```

Do you also want to retrieve the value of the number of clicks in Banner ?

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution (really not the best :) You should use one of the other answers.. anyways, make a php file that reads txt file containing the count of visits.. and in your flashbanner just call the php file. It'll add one hit per call..

PHP:

```
<?php 

/** 
 * Create an empty text file called counterlog.txt and  
 * upload to the same directory as the page you want to  
 * count hits for. 
 *  
 * 
 * @Flavius Frantz: YOU DONT NEED THESE:
 * Add this line of code on your page: 
 * <?php include "text_file_hit_counter.php"; ?> 
 */ 

// Open the file for reading 
$fp = fopen("counterlog.txt", "r"); 

// Get the existing count 
$count = fread($fp, 1024); 

// Close the file 
fclose($fp); 

// Add 1 to the existing count 
$count = $count + 1; 

// Display the number of hits 
// If you don't want to display it, comment out this line 
//echo "<p>Page views:" . $count . "</p>"; 

// Reopen the file and erase the contents 
$fp = fopen("counterlog.txt", "w"); 

// Write the new count to the file 
fwrite($fp, $count); 

// Close the file 
fclose($fp); 

?>
```

Example code from: (google: php counter file) http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/text-file-hit-counter
Code is not tested, but looks ok. I only commented just a little..